# Is it possible to generate a thumbnail image of a webpage in a Windows Universal App?

Tags: win-universal-app

It is easy to generate a thumbnail image of a webpage in a Console Application, Windows Forms Application or similar but I have thus far been unsuccessful in finding a way to do it in a Universal App.. which has different/a reduced set of classes from which to call on.

Unless I can find a way from doing it in a Windows Universal App i'm going to have to put this functionality in a service in Azure and call that service from the app instead.

Just to be clear, the webpage i'd like to generate the thumbnail image of is on the web. i.e. www.bbc.co.uk for example.

Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but did you look at [WebView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn299326)?

Answer (score 0):

The possible way in Windows Universal App is loading your webpage in WebView control and use **WebView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync** method to create an image of the current WebView contents and write it to the specified stream.

See [MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn299326) inlcuded simple sample using C# code.

See also the Windows 8.1 Universal sample about this: [XAML WebView control sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7/)
You can easily port it to Windows 10 Universal App